# Calculate months between two dates keeping year in mind using JodaTime

Tags: java, jodatime

I am using this code to calculate no of months between input pastdate and currentdate. It uses JodaTime

```
LocalDate date1 = new LocalDate(installmentStartDate2);
        LocalDate date2 = new LocalDate(new java.util.Date());
        PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime();
        Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);
        int months = difference.getMonths();
        return months + 1;
```

Now when i enter 1 jan 2013 i get 10 as answer. But the problem is get 10 even when i enter 1 jan 2012.

So that means while calculation it doesn't considers year.

What can i do to get correct answer i.e., 22 when i enter 1 jan 2012.

Can JodaTime do that ? If yes ? How ?
If not ? Any other approach  ?

Comment: I don't know if Joda Time can do it or not. With Pure Java but, I would convert both dates to millis and then find the difference by subtraction. Then convert the result into date object to provide year,month and date difference.

Comment: @Srihari: You can't find the number of months by looking at a number of milliseconds, because the length of a month varies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is almost correct.

You can change :

```
PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime();
```

to :

```
PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.months();
```

and it will work also.

Answer (score 20):

You're asking for the difference in years, months and days - so you're getting back 1 year, 10 months and 29 days.

Just use:

```
int months = Months.monthsBetween(date1, date2).getMonths();
```

Or if you really want to use `new Period` and perhaps get days as well you can use:

```
PeriodType monthDay = PeriodType.yearMonthDayTime().withYearsRemoved();
Period difference = new Period(date1, date2, monthDay);
```

You could just use `PeriodType.months()`, but if you're genuinely only interested in the months, I'd use the first snippet above to do it all in a single short-ish statement.

Answer (score 1):

Joda time is good way to dealing with this problem

Create a joda time date object

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.parse("1970-01-01", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
DateTime endDate = DateTime.parse("2015-02-25", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

Difference between two dates in days

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(startDate, endDate).getDays()
```

Difference between two dates in months

```
int months = Months.monthsBetween(startDate.withDayOfMonth(1), endDate.withDayOfMonth(1)).getMonths()
```

Difference between two dates in years

```
int years = Years.yearsBetween(startDate, endDate).getYears();
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using this:

```
ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(earlierDate,date)
```